ExoPlayer stops playing after empty playlist received with HLS
I'm using ExoPlayer in my Android app to play videos using HLS. Sometimes the server returns an empty playlist during playback (only headers without tracks). This happens quite rarely and subsequent reboots return the updated playlist. I can't change this behaviour.
The problem is that ExoPlayer stops playing video after receiving an empty playlist and displays a static image of the last frame. Other players (for example, AvPlayer in iOS) do not have this problem and the video continues to play.
I tried to investigate the problem a little. As far as I can see, before receiving an empty playlist, the player first makes a request for an m3u8 file, and then requests for ts files. And this repeats periodically. But when the player receives an empty playlist, requests for ts files disappear and only requests for playlist updates are sending.
When I look into with the debugger, I see that after receiving an empty playlist, the onLoadCompleted method in the DefaultHlsPlaylistTracker class stops being called. This seems to point to the source of the problem, but I can't quite figure it out.
How to make ExoPlayer ignore empty playlists?
Update: onPlaylistError is also firing with error HlsPlaylistTracker.PlaylistStuckException. But no player callbacks fired.
